# Extending 'depot' app to include total items in cart

Tags: ruby-on-rails, depot

I'm working my way through creating the depot app from the book 'agile web development with rails'. I'm wanting to change its functionality so that instead of the cart appearing in the side column, I instead get a statement with '(x) items currently in your cart'.

I've got this code:

line_items controller (items that are in the cart):

```
def create
@cart = current_cart
product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
@line_item = @cart.add_product(product.id)

respond_to do |format|
  if @line_item.save
    format.html { redirect_to store_url }
    format.js { @current_item = @line_item }
    format.json { render json: @line_item,
      status: :created, location: @line_item }
  else
    format.html { render action: "new" }
    format.json { render json: @line_item.errors,
      status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
 end
end
```

and the carts controller:

```
def show
begin
  @cart = Cart.find(params[:id])
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
  logger.error "Attempt to access invalid cart #{params[:id]}"
  redirect_to store_url, notice: 'Invalid cart'
else
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # show.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @cart }
  end
 end
end
```

How do I reference the cart from the application layout view so that I can change the '(x) items' to the current number of items in the cart? I've tried `@total_cart.line_items` and all other variations I can think of.

EDIT: I've got code in the cart model that has `current_item.quantity` - how would I reference this in the application layout view, as this is the value I want? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would add a method to your cart called item_count that will add up the number of items in the cart.

```
def item_count
  line_items.inject{|sum, line_item| sum + line_items.quantity
end
```

Then in your application layout view, you could simply reference @cart.item_count.